# How can i connect MariaDB from vps

Tags: mariadb, vps

This is my VPS - Database server:

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server version: 10.0.32-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
- Protocol version: 10
- User: admin@localhost
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

This is more info:

- Hostname Server: digiblogs.info
- Port: 2017

I download and import mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar to NetBeans IDE.
And my code, but it was not worked:

```
>     Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://digiblogs.info:2017/database_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8", "user", "pass");
```

I got Exception

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=digiblogs.info)(port=2017)(type=master) : Connection timed out: connect

Thank so much for your help

Comment: A CONNECTION_TIMEOUT is usually the result of a firewall dropping packs on their way to the destination host. Where is this VPS hosted? Have you opened up the firewall to allow the connections? Your connection string appears to be using port `2017` - this is not the default for MariaDB, have you manually changed this in configuration?

Comment: How can i do it? It is Firewall Options

Comment: Enable Firewall No
Enable DHCP No
Enable NDP Yes
Allow Router Advertisement No
MAC Filter Yes
IP Filter No
log_level_in nolog
log_level_out nolog
Input Policy DROP
Output Policy ACCEPT